# Count if a User ID exists in one or another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three (I inherited them) tables, a users table, a course table and a test table from which I need to measure activity of a user. For instance, the following query will get me the count of users in one of the sets -

```
SELECT COUNT(Users.ID), `CourseSessions`.`CourseID`
FROM `Users`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `CourseSessions`
ON `Users`.`ID` = `CourseSessions`.`UserID`
WHERE `Users`.`CredentialID` IN (2, 3)
AND `CourseSessions`.`CourseID` IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
AND `CourseSessions`.`TimeIn` BETWEEN '2012-06-01' AND '2012-12-31'
GROUP BY `CourseSessions`.`CourseID`;
```

With a result like this -

```
COUNT, CourseID 
32     1
43     2 
31     3
49     4
36     5
21     6
5      7
2      15
```

I can change CourseSessions to TestResults for another set of numbers. The problem comes in when someone either just takes the course or just takes the test.

What I need to be able to do is count a user one time if they exist in either or both tables. Given the following -

```
User     Course.courseID     Test.courseID
A              1
B              1                  1
C                                 1
```

The count for courseID 1 should be 3.

I have been looking at this for a couple of hours and thought maybe I should do a SUM...IF but that didn't work as expected. I have tried sub-selects, but I end up with too many columns. All in all I have gotten pretty wrapped around the axle on this one.

How can I get a single count when a piece of data exists for a user in two tables?

Comment: A SQL Fiddle with some sample data would be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea there was a sql fiddle.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Can one given user take part to the same course/test several times (same `CourseID`), and do you want to count her several times in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT COUNT(CoursesTest.UserID), CourseID
FROM (
    SELECT UserID, CourseID
    FROM CourseSessions
    WHERE TimeIn BETWEEN '2012-06-01' AND '2012-12-31'
    -- extra filters on CourseSessions here
    UNION

    SELECT UserID, CourseID
    FROM TestResults
    -- extra filters on TestResults here
) AS CoursesTest
JOIN Users ON Users.ID = CoursesTest.UserID
WHERE
    Users.CredentialID IN (2, 3)
    AND CoursesTest.CourseID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
GROUP BY CourseID
```

I think the query would be a bit faster if you filtered on `CourseID` earlier, i.e. inside the sub-query. This means duplicating the `IN` condition, but I do not think MySQL is smart enough to optimize the query otherwise.

```
SELECT COUNT(CoursesTest.UserID), CourseID
FROM (
    SELECT UserID, CourseID
    FROM CourseSessions
    WHERE TimeIn BETWEEN '2012-06-01' AND '2012-12-31'
    AND CourseID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
    -- extra filters on CourseSessions here

    UNION

    SELECT UserID, CourseID
    FROM TestResults
    WHERE CourseID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
    -- extra filters on TestResults here

) AS CoursesTest
JOIN Users ON Users.ID = CoursesTest.UserID
WHERE Users.CredentialD IN (2, 3)
GROUP BY CourseID
```

Comment: The syntax for this fails. Unknown column Users.ID

Comment: @JayBlanchard Indeed, table `Users` did not exist in the previous version. This should be fixed now.

Comment: I had figured it out just about the same time that you did. Thanks!